# I don't know how to make this equation work! please. Matlab

Tags: matlab, temperature

I'm trying to calculate the adiabatic flame temperature. I have this script, I'm trying to get a value of T out, how do I make it work? Or is there a better way of doing it?

```
HRxn=((4*-393.5)+(5*-241.83)-(-124.73))*1000; %dH reaction
C=(240.2*298)+(1.51*298^2)-(9.2e-5*298^3)+(1.25e-8*298^4);%298 evaluated

X=(240.2*T)+(1.51*T.^2)-(9.2e-5*T.^3)+(1.25e-8*T.^4);
S=solve(HRxn+(X-C)==0,T)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value out of it you would expect? Which value do you get instead? Do you need help with the formula itself or its actual implementation?

Answer (score 1):

So, basically, you want to solve a quartic polynomial? Then just use `roots`:

```
HRxn         = 1e3 * ((4*-393.5) + (5*-241.83) + 124.73);
coefficients = [1.25e-8  -9.2e-5  1.51  240.2];
constant     = HRxn - coefficients * 298.^(4:-1:1).';
quartic      = [coefficients  constant];

R = roots(quartic);
flame_temperature = R(imag(R)==0 & R > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
syms T
```

before your lines of code, because you didn't defined it before. Then your solution are made visible by

```
disp(S)
```

Comment: that makes the script run but it doesnt produce a usable answer

Comment: This will include the complex-valued and negative solutions. I think an "adiabatic flame temperature" should only be positive :)

Answer (score -1):

i think you should give more information of what you want to do,

```
HRxn=((4*-393.5)+(5*-241.83)-(-124.73))*1000; %dH reaction
C=(240.2*298)+(1.51*298^2)-(9.2e-5*298^3)+(1.25e-8*298^4);%298 evaluated

X=(240.2*T)+(1.51*T.^2)-(9.2e-5*T.^3)+(1.25e-8*T.^4);
S=solve(HRxn+(X-C)==0,T)
```

first and second lines are const. i do not see a point of the equations.

```
HRxn = -2658420
C = 2.033375664162000e+05
```

So what you want to do is

`F(T)=-2658420+(240.2*T)+(1.51*T.^2)-(9.2e-5*T.^3)+(1.25e-*T.^4)-.033375664162000e+05; %this is HRxn+(X-C)
syms T;
S=solve(F,T);`
For me it does not make sense, you have just one variable "T". What do you want to do with solve.

```
F(T) =(944473296573929*T^4)/75557863725914323419136 - (6788401819125115*T^3)/73786976294838206464 + (151*T^2)/100 + (1201*T)/5 - 98329241254705015/34359738368
```

That is what you get.

Unless you are looking for the Roots of the equiation. Then you need the coeff. of F(T).

```
p=[-8 -5 1.51 240.2 -2.861800000091987e+06 ]; %coeff from T^4...T^0
r = roots(p);
r =-17.4518 +17.3032i
   -17.4518 -17.3032i
    17.1393 +17.2782i
    17.1393 -17.2782i
```

I hope this is what you need, i could have made mistakes with the numbers, but i think you get the idea.